# vuejs select option default value not being set

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

ExpensesControls component:

```
<template>
    <div class="expenses-controls">
        <select :value="selectedMonth" class="expense-month-select">
            <option
                v-for="(month, i) in months"
                :key="i"
                :value="month"
            >{{ month }}</option>
        </select>
        <select :value="2021" class="expense-year-select">
            <option
                v-for="(year, i) in years"
                :key="i"
                :value="year"
            >{{ year }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props : {
        months        : Array,
        years         : Array,
        selectedMonth : String,
        selectedYear  : Number,
    },
}
</script>
```

ExpensesCard component:

```
<template>
    <panel class="expenses-card">
        <template v-slot:body>
            <expenses-controls
                :months="months"
                :years="expenseYears"
                :selectedMonth="selectedMonth"
                :selectedYear="selectedYear"
            ></expenses-controls>
        </template>
    </panel>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';
import Panel                    from '@/components/Panel';
import moment                   from 'moment';
import Spinner                  from '@/components/Spinner';
import DataTable                from '@/components/Expenses/DataTable/Datatable';
import ExpensesControls         from '@/components/Expenses/ExpensesControls.vue';

const now    = moment();
const months = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December',
];

const fields = [
    {
        id    : 'date',
        title : 'Date',
    },
    {
        id    : 'description',
        title : 'Description',
    },
    {
        id    : 'category',
        title : 'Category',
    },
    {
        id    : 'amount',
        title : 'Amount',
    },
];

export default {
    components : {
        Panel,
        Spinner,
        DataTable,
        ExpensesControls,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            months           : months,
            selectedYear     : +now.format('YYYY'),
            selectedMonth    : now.format('MMMM'),
            fields           : fields,
            filterRowToggle  : false,
            insertRowToggle  : false,
            rows             : [],
        }
    },
    computed : {
    ...mapState({
        token              : state => state.token,
        expenses           : state => state.expensesStore.expenses,
        expenseYears       : state => state.expensesStore.expenseYears,
        initializedRequest : state => state.expensesStore.initializedRequest,
    }),
},
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to set the default selected year in this select option to the current year 2021. Currently I hard coded 2021 before using `selectedYear` to see if it worked and so far it has not worked. The default selection of the month does work and shows February as the default so not sure why the year one does not work.

I have included the relevant code and a screenshot.

Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: @Dan updated code. Nevertheless `:value="2021"` is where I'm debugging

Comment: Why do you use v-bind in front of 2021? 2021 is obviously not a variable, therefore it shouldn't be set dynamically?

Comment: @mpm as far as I know whatever is in "" can be any valid JS expression no so in this case it would be the integer 2021?,

Comment: @Dan `{{years }}` is an array of years like `[2020, 2021, 2019]` etc.

Comment: @Dan you might be right, `years` could be empty initially as they are set via ajax, what confuses me is that for the select option where months is used,  that one works.

Comment: @Dan you are right, it was empty, I did `console.log(this.years)` in `created()` for the ExpensesControls component. The reason I don't want to use `v-model` is that when a user selects a different year I want to emit and event with what he selected. This would throw an error about a child component overriding parent component props/data.

Comment: I know watchers watch/listen for property changes. Is using watchers the usual way to "wait for ajax to complete and then do x()"?